# Debian автозагрузка

Tags: debian, grub, linux

В общем в `debian` в `network/if-up.d/` попало, очень злое что то. Как через `GRUB` можно загрузиться без `network/if-up.d/` или как можно очистить находящийся там файл?

Comment: @avengerweb, во-первыхБ это вопрос на [РутКод][1] или [БитКод][2], а во-вторых, попробуйте загрузиться с флешки или LiveCD.

  [1]: http://admin.hashcode.ru/
  [2]: http://user.hashcode.ru/

Comment: Возможно [это](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-recover-root-password-under-linux-with-single-user-mode/) поможет Вам.

Здесь описано, как загрузиться в single user mode. Делее правьте свой /etc/network/...

Comment: в single оно все равно подгружаеться

Comment: нет возможности подключить флешку

Comment: Значит проблема не в network скриптах. 

Попробуйте [как здесь](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=109612).

Comment: Там бесконечный цикл... Команда на запуск его.

Comment: Где там? 

Вместо нормальной загрузки через init надо поставить /bin/sh в строке загрузки. 

Попасть в него удалось?

Comment: Проблема в нетворк, там был бесконечный цикл, запуск через bash и вправду спас. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший вариант через live-cd загрузитесь, там примонтируете корень и почитите.

Comment: чем же это лучший вариант ? у меня например в рабочей станции нет cd привода, т.к. я подобный девайс раз в сто лет использую.

Comment: Так и не надо подобные девайсы использовать. Как вариант, подобная флешка создается в течении пары минут.

Comment: Не надо девайсы без DVD использовать ? :) lol я вообще удивляюсь зачем их до сих пор делают.

@spirit а если физ доступа нет ? есть индус и ipkvm ? нормальный ответ  `init=/bin/sh`

Comment: "Не надо девайсы без DVD использовать"
я пытался сказать обратное, но Вы меня не поняли. 
"lol я вообще удивляюсь зачем их до сих пор делают."
lol их еще долго будут делать =)

Answer (score 0):

В строке GRUB нажми `e` добавь в конец  `init=/bin/bash` нажми `f10`

загрузишься в шелл пиши

```
mount -a 
mount / -o remount,rw
```

и можно править файл

```
nano /etc/network/if-up.d/*
```